# Reverse axis in image r

Tags: r, image, axis

Does anyone know a good way to reverse an axis lets say the y-axis, without effecting the plot, in the function `image`?

Lets say I want to make the following plot

`image(1:10,1:10,matrix(1:100,10,10))`.

This works fine but what if I want to display my y-axis going from `10:1`. `image` doesn't let you do `image(10:1,1:10,matrix(1:100,10,10))`. Do I have to create my own axis and add them to the plot or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ylim`:

```
image(1:10,1:10,matrix(1:100,10,10), ylim=c(10,1))
```

Comment: Sorry this works but it also reverses the image too. Anyway to this without revering image? Maybe just overlay another blank image using `par(new=TRUE)`. I'd try this now but need to get some sleep. I'm editing my question to be more specific. Apologies and thanks.

Comment: @CCurtis Hm sorry, but I think I don't get what you need. Anyway, have a good night. :)

Comment: If you overlay your desired `image` plot over an `image` plot of an NA matrix of the same dimensions you can reverse the axis of the NA plot using ylim and specify no axis for your desired plot. This lets me reverse the axis without having any-changes to my desired plot. Thanks for your help.